# Selenium and Node.js: simple idea. Is it possible?

Tags: node.js, csv, selenium-ide

For work I need to extract data from websites and write this data in in a CSV file, at this stage I'm using Selenium and Perl (and this very powerful couple) but yesterday I thinked to this solution:

Selenium IDE ---via JS--->Web app on Node.js Webserver------> CSV

Do you think is it possible? Or there is another "elegant" solutions?

The idea is general, so I can use for data storage, but the testers can use this for improving their tests using the stored variables, so it's for general purpose.

Answer (score 1):

For purpose of scraping you can use `jsdom` module like shown here

http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs

for purpose of generating CSV this module is nice

https://github.com/koles/ya-csv

But there are easier ways to do it like using Mechanize in Perl, Ruby, Python

Comment: I saw the first link yesterday for check my "idea" before posting, it's very useful but (the same for 2nd link) but its not the thing that I need.

With SeleniumIDE not only me but also the sales agents or other not IT staff can write a routine for web scraping. Just this BTW thanks :)